# How to import text to JList?

Tags: java, string, swing, nullpointerexception, jlist

**Text file:**

```
32|Chan|2019-11-29|14:12:01.346
```

**Code:**

```
DefaultListModel<String> listModel;
public LogActivity() {

    initComponents();

    LoginInfo login = new LoginInfo();
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(login.getLogoutRecord());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String read = br.readLine();
        
        while(read != null)
        {
            listModel.addElement(read);//add data to list model object
        }
        logoutList.setModel(listModel);//store  listmodel to logoutlist object
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LogActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LogActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to display my text file into a `Jlist`, but I keep on getting this exception.

```
Error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: the link you sent is not about jlist.

Comment: you are not initializing your list model, it is null, so you get NullPointerException when trying to `addElement` to it. try `DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: yes, thank you. But now the GUI doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Note that in the code you provided the file is not advanced. You don't read each line. You just read a single line and check in the while loop if it is null. If it is not, you enter the while loop and the whole process repeats, never leaving the loop.

Comment: *"But now.."* .. you should ask a new question. Add a [mre].